# If $Z$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, then $Z$ is a function of $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My book claims that if $Z$ is a random variable and $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, then $Y$ is a function of $X$ and does not depend on $\omega \in \Omega$. I can't follow the proof in the book.

> If $Z$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, then for each $z\in\mathbb{R}$, $\{Z = z\} = \{X \in B_z\}$ for some Borel $B_z \subset \mathbb{R}$ (make sense to me). Then $Z = f(X)$ where $f$ is defined by $f(x) =z$ for all $x\in B_z$ (Huh?).

The second sentence does not make sense to me. For example, what if $x\notin B_z$?

I tried to write my own proof but had some problem in the last step: Let $\omega_1 \ne \omega_2$ and $X(\omega_1) = X(\omega_2)$. We want to show that $Z(\omega_1)=Z(\omega_2)$. For any Borel set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$, we consider the set $\{X \in B\}$. We either have both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are in $\{X \in B\}$, or we have both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are not in $\{X \in B\}$.

In particular, for $B_z$, if both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are in $B_z$, then $Z(\omega_1 ) = Z(\omega_2) = z$. If $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are not in $B_z$, then I got stuck.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oops, typo.

Comment: Well, even though the highlighted argument can be made legit, it still does not provide any useful information unless we establish some measurability on $f$. A standard argument uses the machinery called *monotone class theorem*, and the result ensures that $Z = f(X)$ for some Borel measurable $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee To provide some context, we are discussing the definition of $E(Y\mid X)$ as a random variable. The definition requires that $E(Y\mid X)$ to be $\sigma(X)$-measurable. The quote talks about why we require that. The author did not mention anything about the theorem that you mentioned.

Comment: What is your source? The approach you explain in your post is the naïve one, which works for discrete random variables and fails utterly in the general case.

Comment: @Did I am reading _First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory_ by Jeffrey S. Rosenthal

Comment: Don't they assume that $Z$ is discrete?

Comment: @Did Nope. Why must they assume $Z$ to be discrete?

Answer (score 0):

If $X(\omega_1)=X(\omega_2)$ and $Z(\omega_1)\ne Z(\omega_2)$, then there is a Borel set $B$ s.t. $Z(\omega_1)\in B$ and $Z(\omega_2)\notin B$. Since $Z$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, $Z^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(A)$ for some Borel set $A$ s.t. $X(\omega_1)\in A$ and $X(\omega_2)\notin A$, which is a contradiction.

This gives a measurable function $f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is the range of $X$, s.t. $Z(\omega)=f(X(\omega))$.

Comment: How does this specify a measurable $f$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins This does not specify $f$. It implies that $Z=f\circ X$ for some function $f$ on the range of $X$. $f$ is $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}}$-measurable because for any $B\in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$, $f^{-1}(B)=\mathcal{X}\cap A$ for some $A\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$. This $f$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$ by usual approximation argument.

Comment: The function $f$ is uniquely determined on $\mathcal X$ by $f(x) =z$ for all $x\in Z^{-1}(\{z\})$. But (to play the Devil's Advocate) how does this yield the measurability of $f$ (i.e. the assertion that $f^{-1}(B)=\mathcal X\cap A$ with $A\in\mathcal B_{\Bbb R}$, for each Borel set $B$), unless the range of $Z$ is countable?

Comment: @JohnDawkins $x\in Z^{-1}(\{z\})?$. Anyway, isn't it true that
$$
(f\circ X)^{-1}(B)=Z^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(A) \text{ for some }A\in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}?
$$

Comment: (Sorry, that should be $f(X(\omega)) =z$ if $\omega\in Z^{-1}(\{z\})$.) It's true that $Z^{-1}(B) = (f\circ X)^{-1}(B) = X^{-1}(A)$, where $A:=f^{-1}(B)$. But you still have  to show that $A$ is Borel measurable.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Why? We know that there exists Borel $A$  s.t. $(f\circ X)^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(A)$ ($\because Z\in \sigma(X)$). Then $f^{-1}(B)=\mathcal{X}\cap A$.

Comment: My mistake. I lost track of the fact that you were only looking to define a function $f$ on the range of $X$, and not (as usual) to find Borel $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $Z=f\circ X$.

Comment: @d.k.o. : What if $\mathcal{X}$ is not a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Michael Why would that be a problem? We can extend $f$ to a function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @d.k.o. : How?  That does not seem obvious. It would be easier to do if $\mathcal{X}$ were Borel, just define $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin \mathcal{X}$.

Comment: Perhaps the extension can be done by defining $V$ as the set of all limit points of $\mathcal{X}$ that are not in $\mathcal{X}$ (and so $\mathcal{X} \cup V$ is closed hence Borel), then defining $f(y)=0$ if $y \notin \mathcal{X} \cup V$; and if $y \in V$ define $f(y)$ as a liminf value of $f(x_i)$ over all sequences $\{x_i\}$ in $\mathcal{X}$ such that $x_i\rightarrow y$. But we would need $f$ to be bounded to ensure $f(y)\notin \{-\infty, \infty\}$.

Comment: @Michael Actually, the idea is to extend a simple function $1_{A\cap\mathcal{X}}$ to $1_{A}$ for any $A\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$. Assuming that $f\ge 0$, there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{f_n\}$ measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\cap \mathcal{X}$ s.t. $f_n\to f$. Using the indicators' extensions, we can extend each $f_n$ with some simple function $f'_n$, and we take $f'=\lim_{n\to\infty}f'_n$ if the limit exists (call this set $B$) and $0$, otherwise. Finally, take $f''_n=g_n1_B$. Now, $f''=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n''$ extends $f$ (and $f''$ is a Borel function).

Comment: If you are going to do that, then you may as well prove the entire result as the limit of simple functions. =)  (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) 
 I believe the extension I gave in my previous comment works and is a bit more explicit (in particular, we only need to worry about defining $f(x)$ on the boundary of $\mathcal{X}$). Of course it needs $f$ to be bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your remark "For example, what if $x\notin B_z$?": The author seems to be defining a function $f:\cup_{z\in\mathbb R} B_z\to\mathbb R$ as you described. So if $x\in\cup_{z\in\mathbb R} B_z$, $x\in B_z$ for some $z$, in which case we define $f(x)=z$.