# Prove exist a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

If: $X:(\Omega,A) \to (E,\xi)$ is a random variable
$Y: (\Omega,\sigma(X)) \to (R,B_R)$ is measurable
Then $\exists \rho: (E,\xi) \to (R,B_R)$ measurable so that $\forall w$ $Y(w) = \rho(X(w))$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469254/if-z-is-sigmax-measurable-then-z-is-a-function-of-x#

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/847387/36150)